# vba vlookup loop increment +1

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

This should be an easy question for the seasoned pros.

1) I'm trying to offset the active cell down one each iteration of the loop.

2) I can only move down by one because I'm not sure of the syntax available.

3) I was thinking the_result = the_result + 1 but that doesn't work :(

```
Sub vlookupTest()

search = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

For i = 2 To 5

the_result = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(search, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:G5"), 2, True)

MsgBox the_result

search = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)

Next i


End Sub
```

I can see why the loop only moves down two cells and gets stuck since offset only moves down one from "B2" but not sure of the correct syntax to continually move down in this instance

Comment: You could use the *i* incremented in your loop to work progressively down. e.g. `search = ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not explicitly force the *ActiveCell* to start at `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")` but you subsequently offset from the *ActiveCell*. This seems like a mashup of methods to assign a value into *search*. It's probably best to avoid relying on *ActiveCell* altogether.

```
Sub vlookupTest()
    dim searchTerm as variant, the_result as variant

    searchTerm = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").value
    For i = 2 To 5
        the_result = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(searchTerm , Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:G5"), 2, True)
        MsgBox the_result
        searchTerm = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Offset(i - 1, 0).value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Just as an FYI, the use of *True* as the *range_lookup* parameter in `VLOOKUP` returns an approximate match and F2:F5 must be sorted in an ascending manner.

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveCell never changes in your code.

Replace

```
search = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
```

with

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
search = ActiveCell
```